# Is it okay to define attributes depending on conditionals in the __init__ method for a class?

Tags: python, oop

I have created a class that might be instanced from reading a text file, from converting from another text file or from a future GUI. To explain the situation, I'm using a simple example of the exact same case, but I'm not explaining the exact same situation to avoid making the post too long or give away too much information (maybe a bit dumb, but in this time I'm bound by an NDA).

To create an instance of the class, a string with numbers is passed and also an integer, the integer depends on an attribute the instance of another class that's closely related. If from the text file is read `'124'` and the other value (integer) is `12`, what should be shown in the GUI is `136` (offset by `integer`). I originally created the class like this:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__ (self, number, offset):
        self.number = number
        self.offset = offset
        self.displayValue = number + offset
```

The text file will show `self.number`, but the GUI will show `self.displayValue`, and that won't be a problem. However, if this instance is edited from the GUI (of course, with a setter method), what will be edited will be `self.displayValue` and `number` will have to change depending on this. Also, when reading from another kind of text file, an instance will be created but with arguments that instead will be `displayValue` and `offset` (in these two cases `offset` will be negative because it is already be taken into account), from which what should be computed is `self.number`.

I have seen that I can have if-statements in the **init** method. However, in my case, attribute definitions will change depending on from where the instance is created. I can use the sign of the `offset` argument to decide that, but I'd like to know if that doesn't conflict with best practices. Also, note that if `self.displayValue` is edited with the setter method, `self.number` should be also changed, would it be better to include an update to `self.number` in the `self.displayValue` setter? What would be the best way to do this?

PS: Maybe there's another way to do this with GUIs, I'm still to learn to create them.

Comment: Show what kind of conditional assignments you're referring to.

Comment: @Carcigenicate If offset is negative (or probably None too), then the argument 'number' will be assigned to self.displayValue, and self.number will be calculated from them, otherwise the assignments will be as they are now.

Comment: Ya, I don't see anything obviously wrong with that. You may find though that it's cleaner to handle that outside of the class, and pass in data that's already been processed. It depends on if you consider that to be the responsibility of the class or not.

Comment: I've been thinking about that, but one of the reasons I created the class is because there are several operations and attributes that I want them to have available, and it's much better to have them as part of the class. Also, if I do the processing outside, I'd have to get back the values from which the processing was done outside of it again.